# prevent repetitive code in C#

Tags: c#, .net, events, design-patterns

I'm writing a desktop app in win forms using C#.I use the following code to convert my textbox to numeric textboxes :

```
 private void txtPrice_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
        //   && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
        //   && e.KeyChar != '.')
        //          {
        //           e.Handled = true;
        //          }
        if(!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true; 
        }              
    }
```

is it ant design pattern or technique to write above code only once, and dont write it , each time for every textbox in the form?

Comment: If you are on a single form just set the KeyPress event on multiple TextBox controls to txtPrice_KeyPress.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Subclass the TextBox class, add your numeric checking to it, and use the new text box in place of the usual one.

**Example**
[How to: Create a Numeric Text Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new component called numeric textbox that inherits TextBoxBase class.

Your code you wrote here won't work because someone can copy and paste text values.

You have to override text_change event for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want customisation, Robert's answer is the best way to go. Alternatively, in case you're not aware of it, you could use the [NumericUpDown control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which is built in.

Answer (score 1):

create a method....for example

```
 private void press(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
      //what ever code here,,,,,,i dont care  

    }
```

//i am assuming you are using visual studio.net

//highlight or select your text boxes or text box....

//then go to properties window ,,,,,

//after that click on the lightening icon....or events icon

//then go to your KeyPress event------- and click the drop down button

//after that Add the Method you want to be implemented by the Control.......